# Onchange select box show input box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple code for showing the input box onChange using jquery.

```
<select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
    <option value="MCA">MCA</option>
    <option value="MBA">MBA</option>
    <option value="not_listed">Not Listed</option>
</select>

<input name="dd_number" placeholder="Add New" class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" id="textboxes">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeFunc() {
        var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
        var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
        if (selectedValue == "not_listed") {
            $('#textboxes').show();
        } else {
            alert("Error");
            $('#textboxes').hide();
            }
        }
</script>
```

With this code, I can add only one ( 1 ) input box on a select option from the select field. I need a multi-select and not working. Where is the problem? If I want to select 4 select options, I want to display me 4 input box, or if I click 2 select options to display 2 input box. Thanks all for help!

CODE EDIT WITH PHP FUNCTIONS:

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
<label>Choose dimension product</label>
<select class="select2" name="size_id[]" multiple id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();">
    <?php
        $get_sizes = "select * from sizes";
        $sizes = mysqli_query($con,$get_sizes);
        while($row_size = mysqli_fetch_array($sizes)){
        $size_id = $row_size['id_size'];
        $size_name = $row_size['product_size'];
        $i++;
    ?>
    <option value="not_listed"><?php echo $size_name; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
    <input name="<?php echo $size_name; ?>" placeholder="Product price" class="form-control" type="text" style="display: none" id="textboxes">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeFunc() {
    document.getElementById('textboxcont').innerHTML = '';
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
    var selectedValues = Array.from(document.getElementById('selectBox').selectedOptions).map(el=>el.value);
    //alert(selectedValues)
    for( var i = 0; selectedValues.length > i; ++i ) {
    var i1 = document.createElement("input");
    i1.setAttribute("type", "text");
    i1.setAttribute("name", "<?php echo $size_name; ?>"); 
    // you may want to change this
    // add the file and text to the div
    document.getElementById('textboxcont').appendChild(i1);
    }
    }
    </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to check the `multiple` attribute of the select element, [check here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp)

Comment: Okay, how to do that. I write code how it works now and what I need to do to have a multi displaying input box. @OnkarSingh

Comment: Do you have any snippet of full code, regarding the select options, regarding inputs for better understanding?

Comment: The problem is next, I get options from database, I have over 60 options, if user clicks on the car they need to display him input field for category car if they select car and bike they need to display input fields for car and bike. @Onkar

Comment: That means if users clicks 3 options or 2 options or 10 options they need to get 3 or 2 or 10 input fields. @Onkar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to dynamically add the textinputs, you anyway can add 4 inputs and show hide them, but here is an example of what I think you are trying to achieve. For multiselect you can use a plugin like select2, or you can use the multiselect like below.

```js
function changeFunc() {
  document.getElementById('textboxcont').innerHTML = '';
  var selectBox = document.getElementById("selectBox");
  var selectedValues = Array.from(document.getElementById('selectBox').selectedOptions).map(el=>el.value);
  //alert(selectedValues)
  for( var i = 0; selectedValues.length > i; ++i ) {
      var i1 = document.createElement("input");
      i1.setAttribute("type", "text");
      i1.setAttribute("name", "dd_number"); 
      // you may want to change this
      // add the file and text to the div
      document.getElementById('textboxcont').appendChild(i1);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="selectBox" onchange="changeFunc();" multiple>
    <option value="MCA">MCA</option>
    <option value="MBA">MBA</option>
    <option value="not_listed">Not Listed</option>
</select>

<div id="textboxcont">

</div>
```

Comment: Not working for multi select option. Not showing multi input fields or not showing input fields for selected options

Comment: @Lovetocode you have to press the crtl button to multiselect. Click "Run code snippet" above and then select one option, it will show a textinput, then press "crtl" in your keypad and select another, you will then see 2 input box.

Comment: On your code work, but on my not. I will now edit the question to see my code with PHP functions.

Comment: @Lovetocode you have to add a div with id textboxcont. Like I created <div id="textboxcont"></div>. the textinputs will be dynamically created under that div depending upon selection